# createjs bitmap image rotation makes image jagged in chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, antialiasing, easeljs, createjs

When I try to rotate bitmap image with createjs (not resize, but just rotate) the bitmap image gets jagged in Chrome. In Firefox it is fine.

Here is my code:

```
var backCard = new createjs.Bitmap(assetsLoader.getResult("back"));
backCard.rotation = 24;
stage.addChild(backCard);
stage.update();
```

Any ideas on how to fix this ?

Comment: For me, on Firefox the bitmap gets jagged and on chrome and safari it gets antialiased. But I prefer how it looks on Firefox...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you want to prevent or enable antialiasing on Chrome, since for me Chrome gets rotated bitmaps antialiased and firefox don't, so I'll talk about both things...

**Enable antialiasing**

There's no way of doing this natively, but you can create a workaround if you really want to force antialiasing: adding a blur filter in really small amounts to rotated images. But keep in mind that blur is a really expensive filter that you should avoid using, but in case you use it, you'll need to cache the bitmap after applying the filter to reduce CPU usage.

```
backCard.filters = [new createjs.BlurFilter(2, 2, 1);]; // 2 is blur radius, 1 is blur quality. More quality means more expensive blur.
var bounds = backCard.getBounds();
backCard.cache(bounds.x, bounds.y, bounds.width, bounds.height);
```

**Prevent antialiasing**

I think there's no way of doing so ***yet*** too, but you can use the [next version of EaselJS](https://github.com/CreateJS/EaselJS/tree/master/lib) which allows you to define if objects will be antialiased for the stage, because of WebGL. Note that if WebGL isn't supported on the user's browser EaselJS will fallback to HTML5 Canvas, which will still have antialiasing.

Comment: Thanks, but bluring it eather makes it very blur ..looking bad BlurFilter(2, 2, 1) or make it no different BlurFilter(1, 1, 1)

Comment: On Safari, this code creates a nice antialiasing: `new createjs.BlurFilter(1, 1, 2)`. Note that the quality is set to 2, causing an even more expensive calculation. I would recommend you to leave antialiasing to the browser, instead of trying to workaround a problem that is not on your code.

Comment: Also, I can't test this on chrome since I'm using my project to test the blur and, I don't know why, the filters simply don't appear on chrome...

Comment: 1,1,2 works nice on Chrome so I guess it is solution to the problem. Thanks